# 100% exact Espresso theme for Sublime Text?

Tags: themes, sublimetext, color-scheme, macrabbit-espresso

As the title says I'd like to have my Sublime Text 3 with Espresso's default theme.

I know there's Soda which is a really similar one but I need that specific color scheme instead of Soda's. I've searched around on Google and there's only modified personal versions but I wonder if there's something "official" in the sense that it's looking exactly as the original Espresso color scheme.

Also, is there something that replicates Deamweaver's scheme? This one's for a friend who's starting out and having some difficulties adapting to another color scheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't find a color scheme there is a nice tm-theme editor to build your own scheme: http://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com/#!/editor/theme/Monokai%20Extended%20Mod

Comment: I already knew the editor(thanks for pointing out anyway) but before actually opening Photoshop to get the hexa color codes for all the file types(html, css, js) and putting them into a new theme all by myself I wanted to be sure there's no other option.

Popular code editors usually have themes that resembles color schemes for the other ones and Sublime's been around for a while so I thought there would be an Espresso theme already that I just can't find for some reason...Soda is good but I don't like the fact that the html tags have almost the same color as the attribute and other stuff.

Comment: Oh and by the way there seems to be the theme I'm looking for there, don't know if you linked that for this reason :) there's also a "Dreamweaver one" but it seems a bit off, I don't see the distinctive pink but maybe I have to check my settings.

Comment: I posted this just in case no one else knows a source for an Espresso scheme. But If you are ok with soda you can upload the tm-theme file of soda into the editor and change just the little things (like html color) which you don't like instead of making a new one. Also there are many other schemes which you could use as a source for a new one.

Comment: Well, the fact is Soda's perfect for me except for that specific detail which I honestly don't understand how people can live with, that's a really popular theme but you have no clue whatsoever in your html wether you're looking at a tag or a selector/propriety.Thanks for pointing the link and the process out, I'll do what you just suggested and mark your answer as the Accepted one!